# jQuery error SCRIPT5002: Function expected in IE9 64Bit

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Why do I get the below error in my jQuery script only when it runs on IE9 64Bit? The entire site works well in all other browsers. This is the only browser to throw this error.

My jQuery version in 1.7.2

**Error is:**

```
SCRIPT5002: Function expected 
jq.js, line 430 character 6
```

**This is line 430 Character 6**

```
$('#'+type).insertAfter(self.parent()).show();
```

`+type` is actually `'success'`

`success` is a div that is hidden and stored at the end of the page, and that is moved to the parent.

```
<div id="success">Your message was sent</div>
```

**My Code**

```
$('.msg').click(function() {

    self = $(this);

    var type = $(this).data('type');

        if(type) {
            // ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"/msgr/",
                data:data,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend:function(html){

                },
                success: function(callBack){
                    $('#'+type).insertAfter(self.parent()).show();
                }

                },
                error: function(page_data){

                },
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Give us the context of the bigger picture. You are providing too little information for us to reproduce the problem. Prove your problem by providing a link to the page, or create a jsfiddle that reproduces the error.

Comment: You know that an error on line `n` is in 9/10 cases caused by an error in line `n-m` right?

Comment: show us the code around - IE error messages rarely appear where they actually happen

Comment: For the sake of testing, what happens if you substitute line 430 for `$('#success').insertAfter(self.parent()).show();`?

Comment: @moob Still the same if I do as you say.

Comment: Any help? This is the only thing that does not work. All the rest is good :-)

Comment: `self` is a property of `window` object, and most likely it is read-only in IE. `var self = $(this);` might solve the problem.

Comment: @Teemu You are perfectly right. I remember this script working correctly. The reason I removed the var before it was because I needed it as a `global` to use else where in the file. Now this problem is solved, but the other part wont work :-)

Comment: @jmenezes So you declared `self` instead of renaming it? By renaming you can keep it global, and your `succes` function can find it from the global scope.

Comment: Umm... [embarrassed]. Please post your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is a property of `window` object, which is read-only in some versions of IE.

The simplest solution is to rename the variable (especially in case of a global variable), or some cases limit the use of `self` in a particular function scope by declaring it using `var`.